# Compact Space already CG Space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$ is compactly generated if it's topology is determined as follows:

$U \subset X$ open if and only if $s^{-1}U \subset K$ open for all locally compact spaces $K$ and continuous $s:K \to X$.

I want to know if EVERY compact space is compactly generated.

Comment: Have you tried taking $s$ to be the identity map?

Comment: From where did you get this definition of **compactly generated**? I was raised with another one: $X$ is compactly generated if its topology $\tau$ coincides with the finest topology on $X$ such that all $\tau$-continuous functions $t:C\to X$ where $C$ is a **compact Hausdorff space** are (still) continuous. Don't know yet whether the definitions match. On this my answer to your former question is based.

Comment: Locally compact? That should be compact (probably including Hausdorff). And if you really mean locally compact, how is that notion defined?

Comment: @drhab: From Gerd Laures' "Grundkurs Topologie" ...unfortunately there exist only a German edition :(

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is compact .

We want to show $U$ open iff $s^{-1}[U]$ open in $K$ for all continuous $s: K \to X$.

The left to right implication always holds (it's the definition of continuity of $s$). Suppose then that $U$ satisfies the right hand side condition. In particular we can take $K = X$ as $X$ is compact and $s(x) = x$. By assumption $s^{-1}[U] = U$ is open in $K = X$ so we are done.

Comment: A question aside (let me ask a topologist ;) out of curiosity: what is the most common definition of "compactly generated space"? I am used to Strickland and Frankland: topology is finalized by maps $t:C\to X$ where $C$ is compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @drhab I usually follow Engelking’s and others’  definition of $k$-space.  So if the topology is determined by the compact subsets. This works best in general topology while the mapping definition seems to work better in categorical and algebraic topology settings

Comment: "Mmm... erg jammer" (real pity) that there are distinct definitions of it. I love uniformity in matters like this. Mine agrees with [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space).

Comment: @drhab probably the Hausdorffness matters, though I have no example of the difference yet.

Comment: @drhab In May's (quite nice) book compact = compact Hausdorff and this notion with "test spaces" $K$ that are compact Hausdorff is called $k$-space and this notion of $k$-space + weak Hausdorff ($X$ is weak Hausdorff for every continuous $f: K \to X$ with $K$ compact (Hausdorff, $f[K]$ is closed in $X$) is called compactly generated. This notion is the same as $A \subset X$ is closed iff $A \cap K$ is closed in $K$ for each compact (Hausdorff) subspace of $X$, so the topology of $X$ is determined by its compact Hausdorff subspaces.

Comment: @drhab E.g. the cofinite topology on an infinite set is compact (non-Hausdorff) and not compactly generated in this sense, as its only compact Hausdorff subspaces are the finite ones.

Comment: Thank you Henno. I really appreciate this and will try to keep this example in mind. Also I will put my nose in May's book.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In a compact space $X$ you have $V$ is open $\Leftrightarrow X \backslash V$ is closed $\Leftrightarrow X \backslash V$ is compact.

Also, $s^{-1}(X \backslash V)=Y\backslash s^{-1}(V)$ for all functions $s : X \to Y$.